# IntelliJ code completion: ⇥ key?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Tip of the Day says:
"When using Code Completion, you can accept the currently highlighted selection in the popup list with ⇥ key.
Unlike accepting with the ⏎ key, the selected name will overwrite the rest of the name to the right of the caret. This can be especially useful for replacing one method or variable name with another."

What exactly is ⇥ key?  Does it represent a combination?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

⇥ Is the Tab key.

More Tips/Tricks can be found at IntelliJ's youtube channel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eq3KiAH4IBI